# Error When Loading Images on Local Host Test Server

Tags: html, image, node.js, apache, angularjs

I have a peculiar problem that I just can't seem to find an explanation.

I'm working on an AngularJS site for our family and am integrating data from various web services.  Currently I am working on the photos section which will integrate in photos from our Flickr account.

I have a main page which lists the various photo sets and displays the set's primary photo along with the title.  (Note: I'm using the Flickr 'extras' parameter to return the primary photo's URL in the API calls.)

```
<div data-ng-repeat="p in vm.photoSets">
    <a ng-href="#/photos/{{p.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{p.primary_photo_extras.url_s}}"></img>
    </a>
    <h4>{{p.title._content}}</h4>
</div>
```

When clicking on the photo, the routing will display a page with a list of all the photos from that set, showing the image and the title.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="p in vm.photoSetData.photo">
    <a ng-href="#/photos/{{vm.photoSetId}}/{{p.id}}"
        <img ng-src="{{p.url_s}}"></img>
    </a>
    <h4>{{p.title}}</h4>
</div>
```

Now, here's where the problem is occuring.  When I upload the code to my public website on my hosting provider, everything works just fine.  Both pages display their respective photos.  However, when I attempt to run the site on my local system, either in MAMP or NodeJS (using http-server), the second page gives me an error for each image:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{p.url_s}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: https://farm1.staticflickr.com/37/82749767_e82ff60ce3_m.jpg
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$sce/insecurl?p0=https%3A%2F%2Ffarm1.staticflickr.com%2F37%2F82749767_e82ff60ce3_m.jpg
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bp.url_s%7D%7D&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24sce%3Ainsecurl%5D%20Blocked%20loading%20resource%20from%20url%20not%20allowed%20by%20%24sceDelegate%20policy.%20%20URL%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Ffarm1.staticflickr.com%2F37%2F82749767_e82ff60ce3_m.jpg%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.9%2F%24sce%2Finsecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffarm1.staticflickr.com%252F37%252F82749767_e82ff60ce3_m.jpg
minErr/<@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:78
$interpolate/fn@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:8254
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:11800
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:12061
done@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:7843
completeRequest@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:8026
createHttpBackend/</jsonpDone<@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:7942
jsonpReq/doneWrapper@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:8039
jsonpReq/script.onerror@http://localhost/scripts/angular.js:8053
```

The API call to Flickr is successful and returns the correct data.  In fact, the image title does display!  I've tested it with Firefox, Safari and Chrome...all three browsers fail.

I cannot find any explanation as to why it would work remotely but fail locally.  Also, the images show up on the first page, but not on the second, even though one of the images on the second page is the same image URL as on the first page.  Even going directly to the second page, bypassing the first page, still fails.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  It would be nice to test locally without having to upload to the server each time I make a change.

**Update:**
I have shut off the $sce security to see if that was causing the issue.  Although it resulted in turning the error off, the files still don't load on the local test server.  I have used the developer tools' network monitor and it doesn't even show an attempt to retrieve the files.  AngularJS appears to shut down the retrieval, although the correct path shows up in the DOM.

Comment: This seams to be a security issue with $sce, i recomend you take a look at [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). At the bottom they have and example how to turn it completly off, try it to make sure this is the source of the problem.

Comment: @1st4ck I disabled it and the error went away...but the images don't appear.  The network monitor shows it doesn't even attempt to go out and load them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the symptoms, it just seemed that something was wrong with the second page.  After looking through the DOM, I noticed something strange about the `a` and `img` tags.  It seemed that the entire `img` tag was embedded into the `a` tag.

So, I went back to the `html` markup and noticed the missing closing bracket.  The entire issue was caused by the `a` tag not being properly closed.

I'm still trying to understand the error that AngularJS was throwing and how it would relate to the incorrect markup.